# How to Read information on the next line in csv file to perform calculation of Asset Growth

Tags: dataframe, csv, calculation

```
comp = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/naitm/Desktop/python coding/FFM5/Question 1-1/5_factor_merge.csv')
# Create book equity --> Book value of equity cannot be negative
comp['be'] = comp['seq'] + comp['txditc'] - comp['ps']
comp['be'] = np.where(comp['be'] > 0, comp['be'], np.nan)

# Create operating profitability = total revenue - cost of goods sold - sell expense - admin expense 
#/ book equity
comp['op'] = (comp['revt'] - comp['cogs'] - comp['xsga'] - comp['xint']) / comp['be']
```

these work as all the cell information is in same row.   But I need to calculate asset growth which is on this same current row but also the next row when the same company. How do I access the one on the next row or previous row?  the field is 'at'  so i need:
comp['ag'] = (comp['at']-comp['at'])/comp['at'] #first at is next row, second at is current, third is
next row

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to share sample data in clear text format rather than an image please

Comment: To get the data from the next line, you can use shift(-1).   So if you want next line for `comp['op']`, then you can give `comp['op'].shift(-1)`. You can give shift(1) for prev row, shift(-1) for next row information

Comment: that makes sense Joe... i figured it had to be pretty simple and next one would be comp['op'].shift(1) right

Comment: You got it. See, you are already an expert at it. shift(1) is for prev row, shift(-1) is for next row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is not an answer but just to help you illustrate how shift() works.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,4,5]})
df['B'] = df.A.shift(1)
df['C'] = df.A.shift(-1)

print (df)

   A    B    C
0  1  NaN  2.0   # <--- value of B is NaN as shift of prev row is NaN
1  2  1.0  3.0
2  3  2.0  4.0
3  4  3.0  5.0
4  5  4.0  NaN   # <--- value of C is NaN as shift of next row is NaN
```